# Aliases too long for @ManyToMany associations

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using Oracle10g dialect but hibernate is creating too long table names for ManyToMany associations.

```
new org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect().getMaxAliasLength() == 20
```

Relationship is defined as follows:

**ISImporterProfile**:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="IS_IMPORTER_NODE_PROFILE"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="PROFILE_ID")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="NODE_ID")
        }
    )
private List<ISImporterNode> importerNodes;
```

**ISImporterNode:**

```
@ManyToMany
private List<ISImporterProfile> ISImporterProfiles;
```

Hibernate creates this when getting getISImporterProfiles() on node.

> select isimporter0_.is_importer_node_id as is_importer_node_i1_0_0_,
>   isimporter0_.isimporter_profiles_id as isimporter_profile2_1_0_, 
>   isimporter1_.id as id1_3_1_, isimporter1_.config as config2_3_1_,
>   isimporter1_.config_xslt as config_xslt3_3_1_, isimporter1_.enabled 
>   as enabled4_3_1_, isimporter1_.locked as locked5_3_1_,
>   isimporter1_.name as name6_3_1_, isimporter1_.sync as sync7_3_1_ from 
>   **is_importer_node_isimporter_profiles** isimporter0_, 
>   is_importer_profile isimporter1_  where
>   isimporter0_.isimporter_profiles_id=isimporter1_.id and
>   isimporter0_.is_importer_node_id=?

This of course creates **ORA-00972** exception as it is longer than 30 chars. How can I solve this without having to struggle with NamingStrategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the owner of the relationship (mappedBy), the result will not be the expected result (and you will probably four tables). Plus, your entities must be the Java Bean convention (empty constructor, camelCase attributes and getters/setters) or you probably get problems when you get that property through it's getter.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "importerNodes")
private List<ISImporterProfile> isImporterProfiles;
```

Comment: Yeah, I can live with that, because is* is usually boolean, that's why I left it with upper case.

Comment: why don't use other identifier like appearsOnImporterProfiles, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add `mappedBy = "importerNodes"` to your mapping in `ISImporterNode`

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "importerNodes")
private List<ISImporterProfile> ISImporterProfiles;
```